# Creating Prefabs during AssetPostProcessor from the imported asset

Tags: unity, c#, asset-management

I'm trying to create an automation for our asset pipeline where an imported mesh will automatically be processed into prefabs for each instanced submesh. For example, when I import this FBX `PipelineAsssets.fbx_Scene` it creates the directory `PipelineAssets.fbx_scene_PREFABS` and then fills it with prefabs of each unique instanced submesh from that fbx.

[image]
[image]

The code I have so far accomplishes this task with one major flaw, the MeshFilter components on each of these prefabs are empty.

[image]

Upon inspecting the documentation, I've discovered the problem with my simple attempt at achieving this goal.

> Any references to game objects or meshes will become invalid after the import has been completed. Thus it is not possible to create a new Prefab in a different file from OnPostprocessModel that references meshes in the imported fbx file.
> https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPostprocessor.OnPostprocessModel.html

Nevertheless, I'd still like to accomplish my goal of automatically making prefabs on import of models. While the documentation declares it's not possible within the `OnPostprocessModel` method, maybe there's somewhere else in the `AssetPostProcessing` class where it is possible? Is there maybe another place in the asset importing process that I can hook in to do this?

How can I create prefabs of imported assets during the asset importing process?

For completeness and to help folks investigating this question out, I'm including my source code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class FBXPrefabImport : AssetPostprocessor
{

    private static string MakeValidFileName(string name)
    {
        string invalidChars = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(new string(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()));
        string invalidRegStr = string.Format(@"([{0}]*\.+$)|([{0}]+)", invalidChars);

        return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(name, invalidRegStr, "_");
    }

    private void OnPostprocessModel(GameObject gameObject)
    {
        String path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(assetPath),MakeValidFileName(gameObject.name) +  "_PREFABS");
        DirectoryInfo info =  System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        Stack<GameObject> stack = new Stack<GameObject>();
        Dictionary<Mesh, GameObject> prefabDict = new Dictionary<Mesh, GameObject>();
        stack.Push(gameObject);

        while(stack.Count > 0)
        {
            GameObject stackObject = stack.Pop();
            foreach (Transform childTransform in stackObject.transform)
            {
                MeshFilter meshfilter = childTransform.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
                if (meshfilter != null)
                {
                    if(!prefabDict.ContainsKey(meshfilter.sharedMesh))
                    {
                        prefabDict[meshfilter.sharedMesh] = childTransform.gameObject;
                    } 
                }
                stack.Push(childTransform.gameObject);
            }
        }
        foreach(Mesh mesh in prefabDict.Keys)
        {
            GameObject prefabObject = prefabDict[mesh];
            PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(prefabObject, Path.Combine(info.FullName , MakeValidFileName(prefabObject.name) + ".prefab"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There may be a neater way to do this, but one approach might be to use the EditorCoroutines package to kick off a coroutine that waits until after an AssetDatabase.Refresh and *then* creates the prefabs.

Comment: I'm going to investigate this and see if it's at least workable.

Comment: I have found potentially another option in this thread on the unity forums that I'll pursue further. https://forum.unity.com/threads/calls-to-assetdatabase-createasset-are-restricted-during-asset-importing.1517806/#post-9478780

In it, EditorCoroutines are mentioned as a solution, but the discussion focuses on the more promising solution of using `OnPostprocessAllAssets()` in combination with asset caching things I have yet to understand fully.